# How to use call the same mutation multiple times in a for each loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using React-apollo v2 and I am trying to execute a mutation from a **for each** loop. Lets say i have an array

```
const arrayOfIds = [{id:1},{id:2}, {id:3}]

  <Mutation
    mutation={RUN_TEST}
  >
    {(runTest, { loading }) => (
      <Button
        onClick={() => //here i need to call a function that will loop through idsArray and call RUN_TEST mutation while passing the ID as variable}
      >
        Run test
      </Button>

    )}
  </Mutation>
```

How can i achieve that? I tried something like below but it wont work

```
  try {
      const results = await Promise.all(idsArray.map((item, idx) =>
        runTest({id: item.id}))); 
    } catch (e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 // loop here
    const updateDataInLoop = () => {
            try { 
             arrayOfIds.map(async (item, idx)=>await runTest({id: item.id}))
            } catch e {
              console.log(e)
            } 
      };
```

this example might help,

https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-mutations-forked-o1vmsk?file=/src/index.js